# IE Conditional Statements Displaying in Browser Issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer

I have a Bootstrap ASP.NET MVC 4 project and look perfect across all browsers, except for IE 8 on Windows Server 2003.

When viewing the website the text `<!--[if lt IE 9 !IE]><![endif]--><!--[if lt IE 9 !IE]><!--<![endif]--><!--[if lt IE 9 !IE]><![endif]-->` actually appears on the page, so the browser is ignoring it.

**HTML**

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9 !IE]>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryold")
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9 !IE]><!-->
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <!--<![endif]-->
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/freelance")

    <!-- IE8 support for HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9 !IE]>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ie9")
    <![endif]-->
```

Any help resolving this issue would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `!IE` cancels out your conditional statement.

`!IE` means "target any other browser EXCEPT IE"

Just get rid of it

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryold")
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<!--<![endif]-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/freelance")

<!-- IE8 support for HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ie9")
<![endif]-->
```

Check [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) for more info.